# Logic App query Azure Table using HTTP and Managed Identity authentication

Tags: azure-storage, azure-logic-apps, azure-table-storage, azure-managed-identity

I am trying to query Azure Table using the HTTP connector without success.

According to this document managed identity authentication is now possible for Azure Table:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/tables/authorize-managed-identity

I have authorized the managed identity of the consumption logic app in the azure table using PowerShell as the documentation sugests.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/tables/assign-azure-role-data-access?tabs=powershell

```
New-AzRoleAssignment -ObjectID xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx `
 -RoleDefinitionName "Storage Table Data Contributor" `
 -Scope  "/subscriptions/<subscription>/resourceGroups/<resource-group>/providers/Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts/<storage-account>/tableServices/default/tables/<table>"
```

Then in the logic app I've filled the request as documented in:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/storageservices/query-tables#request-headers

[image: Screenshot of the configs]

The run fails with forbidden missing authorization header.

```
"body": {
     "odata.error": {
         "code": "AuthenticationFailed",
         "message": {
             "lang": "en-US",
             "value": "Server failed to authenticate the request. Make sure the value of Authorization header is formed correctly including the signature.\nRequestId:8d5dbe66-d002-0005-26e6-45da23000000\nTime:2022-04-01T16:35:57.2213453Z"
         }
     }
 }
```

Any ideas?

Comment: you granted permission to only one table and you are trying to query all the tables  so it wont work. I tried granting `Storage Table Data Contributor"` at the storage level and or this particular request it was ok on my side

Comment: Is there any reason why you don’t use the built in actions for what you’re doing?

Comment: Hello @Thomas, I've ended up being able to query the table by changing my headers.
Basically with GET operation maintaining the url and:
Accept: application/json;odata=nometadata
Content-Type: application/xml
x-ms-version: 2019-07-07

Comment: Hello @Skin. Mainly for security compliance. We have to use managed identity whenever possible.

Answer (score 2):

So Basically with the setup bellow I was able to successfully query the Azure Table over HTTP

**Headers:**

[image]

**Result:**

[image]